# How to stop visual studio generate typescript js and js.map files while publishing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, configuration, typescript, publishing

I set up my project that `combine javascript output into file` to `$(ProjectDir)dist\output.js` and uncheck `generate source maps`.

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Typescript -> Project -> Automatically compile Typescript files which are not part of a project` is unchecked as well.

While building and running project from visual studio, it works as expected: generate only `output.js` files.

However while publishing my project, it still generates js and js.map file foreach .ts files.

When I check `myproject.pubxml.user` file, it says:

```
<File Include="app/app.module.js">
  <publishTime>06/16/2015 17:41:13</publishTime>
</File>
<File Include="app/app.module.js.map">
  <publishTime>06/16/2015 17:41:13</publishTime>
</File>
<File Include="app/app.routes.js">
  <publishTime>06/16/2015 17:41:13</publishTime>
</File>
<File Include="app/app.routes.js.map">
  <publishTime>06/16/2015 17:41:13</publishTime>
</File>
<File Include="app/controllers/account/loginController.js">
  <publishTime>06/16/2015 17:41:13</publishTime>
</File>
```

How can I stop Visual Studio from generating those unwanted .js and map.js files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However while publishing my project, it still generates js and js.map file foreach .ts files.

You probably have different config for `debug` and `release`. Make them the same.

Comment: Ah that's true. Dealing with typescript confuses me. Thanks a lot.,